# Mailchimp: How to keep track of who I've already invited?

Tags: mailchimp

I have a Mailchimp news list with about 5,000 users. I want to invite them to use my product, gradually in batches.

These batches will be pretty arbitrary - I want to invite people I know personally first, then some people who's volunteered to be beta testers, then maybe everyone from a particular country, etc.

My question is this: how can I keep track of who I've already invited and who I haven't, so I don't end up inviting the same people twice?

It looks as though I should set up a campaign for each batch.

But then once I've sent the emails for that campaign, how can I flag those users as having already been invited?

Maybe I need to make a segment for each campaign, and make sure users aren't in more than one segment?

Comment: Isn't this as simple as putting it in a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude/include people who have been sent/not sent specific previous emails using the 'Campaign activity' option in custom segments.

See image attached:
[image]

You can use these conditions in combination, e.g.

Recipient matches all of the following:

- Is from Germany
- Was not sent Campaign [x]
- Was not sent Campaign [y]